# In AWK, skip the rest of the current action?

Tags: awk

Thanks for looking.

I have an AWK script with something like this;

```
/^test/{
  if ($2 == "2") {
    # What goes here?
  }

  # Do some more stuff with lines that match test, but $2 != "2".
}


NR>1 {
  print $0
}
```

I'd like to skip the rest of the action, but process the rest of the patterns/actions on the same line.

I've tried `return` but this isn't a function.
I've tried `next` but that skips the rest of the patterns/actions for the current line.

For now I've wrapped the rest of the `^test` action in the `if` statement's `else`, but I was wondering if there was a better approach.

Not sure this matters but I am using `gawk` on OSX, installed via `brew` (for better compatibility with my target OS).

### Update (w/solution):

Edits: Expanded code sample based on @karakfa's answer.

```
BEGIN{
  keepLastLine = 1;
}
/^test/ && !keepLastLine{
  printLine = 1;
  print $0;
  next;
}

/^test/ && keepLastLine{
  printLine = 0;
  next;
}

/^foo/{
  # This is where I have the rest of my logic (approx 100 lines), 
  # including updates to printLine and keepLastLine
}

NR>1 {
  if (printLine) {
    print $0
  }
}
```

This will work for me, I even like it better that what I was thinking of.

However I do wonder what if my keepLastLine condition was only accessible in a for loop?

I gather from what @karakfa has said, there isn't a control structure for exiting only an action, and continuing with other patterns, so that would have to be implemented with a flag of some sort (not unlike @RavinderSingh13's answer).

Comment: Skip where? It's not clear with your description, show at least some pseudo-code or with your `return` inside.

Comment: what `else` are you looking for?

Comment: @karakfa I specifically stated in my question that I'd already worked around this issue with the `else`, so your answer adds nothing to my issue. I use `else` now, but I'd rather not have the else wrap >100 lines of my real code because it ends up with nesting that is already 8 nestings deep. 7 wouldn't be that much better, and I certainly could extract a function or 2. My question remains; is there a way to `return` from inside an action, or `next` without abandoning the following patterns and actions.

Comment: OK, the whole purpose of life of  `else` is to solve this issue and there is no other keyword to help you with that.  But for some reason you don't want it please see the update on my answer for an alternative.

Comment: The solution you posted in your question is using inversion of control. Earlier/lower level parts of your code are telling later/higher level parts what to do. That's control coupling and so bad software. Instead have your earlier/lower level code just report what it did or what condition is otherwise now true and let the later/higher level code decide what to do given that condition. If you want help then post a new question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the magic keyword you're looking for is `else`

```
/^test/{ if($2==2) {  } # do something
         else {  }      # do something else  
       }

NR>1                    # {print $0} is implied.
```

for some reason if you don't want to use `else` just move up condition one up (flatten the hierarchy)

```
/^test/ && $2==2 {  } # do something
/^test/ && $2!=2 {  } # do something else  
# other action{statement}s
```

Answer (score 3):

If I got it correct could you please try following. I am creating a variable named `flag` here which will be chedked if condition inside `test` block for checking if 2nd field is 2 is TRUE then it will be SET. When it is SET so rest of statements in `test` BLOCK will NOT be executed. Also resetting flag's value before read starts for a line too.

```
awk '
{
 found=""
}
/^test/{
  if ($2 == "2") {
    # What goes here?
    found=1
  }
  if(!found){
  # Do some more stuff with lines that match test, but $2 != "2".
  }
}
NR>1 {
  print $0
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Testing of code here:***

Let's say following is the Input_file:

```
cat Input_file
file
test 2 file
test
abcd
```

After running code following we will get following output, where if any line is having `test` keyword and NOT having `$2==2` then also it will execute statements outside of `test` condition.

```
awk '
{
 found=""
}
/^test/{
  if ($2 == "2") {
    print "# What goes here?"
    found=1
  }
  if(!found){
   print "Do some more stuff with lines that match test, but $2 != 2"
  }
}
NR>1 {
  print $0
}'   Input_file
# What goes here?
test 2 file
Do some more stuff with lines that match test, but $2 != 2
test
abcd
```